# Can't reach IP in same subnet

Tags: ip, routing

I recently changed my home router (192.168.1.1) subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 and encountered some problems. When my computer uses a 192.168.2.XXX address I can't access my printer on 192.168.1.13, but I can access my NAS on 192.168.1.10. Everything works fine if I set IP on PC to 192.168.1.XXX.

I also tried with ping:

- PC -> Router **WORKING**
- PC -> Printer **NOT WORKING**
- PC -> NAS **WORKING**
- Router -> PC **NOT WORKING**
- Router -> Printer **WORKING**
- Router -> NAS **WORKING**

Also note that:

- Every device has a 255.255.0.0 subnet mask
- My computer and printer are connected to router via external switch, while NAS is connected directly to router port
- I tried to restart router and switch

Answer (score 2):

All devices on the subnet need to have the same netmask.  In the case of the printer I suspect the netmask is 255.255.**255**.0 so it is not picking up on traffic destined for it.  Simply change the netmask in the printer.  (You need to change all devices to have the same netmask to make sure they can communicate with each other)

Comment: I have seen many printers intended for home use do not properly handle changes to the subnet mask, so it may not matter what the printer's settings say.

Comment: I'm not sure how the netmask could affect incoming traffic. (Even with the wrong netmask, from the printer's PoV the traffic wouldn't be _invalid_, it could equally well have been routed to it...) Though maybe the issue is that it doesn't know how to properly _reply_ to it.

Comment: As I said every device including printer has a 255.255.0.0 mask in their network settings.

Answer (score -3):

192.x.x.x is a class C address.

192.168.1.1 and 198.168.2.x will never be on the same network, and therefore can never be in the same subnet.

Comment: With a subnet mask of 21 bits or fewer, yes they certainly can be on the same network.

Comment: @CharlesBurge a class C address has a max of 254 hosts per network.  Easiest way to prove this is use an [online subnet calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=C) and you will quickly see that 255.255.0.0 isn't a valid subnet mask for a class C address.

Comment: I just tested it with 2 *actual* computers.  Comp1 = 192.168.1.1 and Comp2 = 192.168.2.2.  Both have 21-bit mask.  Yes, they can see each other.

Comment: To make it always work tho, the OP could move to a class A (or class b) addresses such as 10.10.1.1 and the use a mask 256.255.0.0 then any IP from 10.10.1.1 to 10.10.255.254 would be in the same subnet.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The concept of address classes pretty much went away with the introduction of CIDR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Comment: Perhaps... however, I've solved several home grade equipment connectivity issues by following the class-ful networking rules.  I'm no expert tho.